# Does one need to create an interface or implemented class to Mockito.mock()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I read the tutorials but did not understand - how much of the mocked object should be implemented. Are we passing an interface or the entire implemented class to mock()?

What if you do not have the implementation? Do you need to create an interface - **suppose you omit some methods out of ignorance of the actual implementation...**

from example at mockito.org [here](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verification)

```
//mock creation
 List mockedList = mock(List.class);
```

Do I need to create a class 'List' with the methods of the android List class?

Comment: Either an interface or a class works

Comment: Did you try? What did you find out?

Comment: You can either provide an interface or a concrete class, Mockito accepts both of them

Comment: @Arkadiy does one need to create an interface? suppose you omit some methods from ignorance of the real class...

Comment: No, you don't need to have an interface. Any class that is not `final` can be mocked, whether it implements any interfaces or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito's default implementation for every method is given by [RETURNS_DEFAULTS](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEFAULTS), which (unless otherwise configured) defers to [ReturnsEmptyValues](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/defaultanswers/ReturnsEmptyValues.html):

> Default answer of every Mockito mock.
>
> - Returns appropriate primitive for primitive-returning methods
> - Returns consistent values for primitive wrapper classes (e.g. int-returning method returns 0 and Integer-returning method returns 0,
>     too)
> - Returns empty collection for collection-returning methods (works for most commonly used collection types)
> - Returns description of mock for toString() method
> - Returns zero if references are equals otherwise    non-zero for Comparable#compareTo(T other) method (see issue 184)
> - Returns an java.util.Optional#empty() empty Optional for Optional    (see issue 191).
> - Returns null for everything else

**For any mockable but unstubbed method on a class that you pass to `Mockito.mock()`, the mock method will have this behavior by default, regardless of whether you passed in a concrete class or an interface.** In fact, Mockito encourages you to only stub the methods that are valuable to your system under test, and to let the defaults work for everything else. This is also the case if you "forget" to stub a method, or if new methods are added after you've written your test.

Note that for `Mockito.spy`, the default behavior is to delegate to (a copy of) the instance you pass to `spy`, and that by passing additional parameters to `Mockito.mock` you can change this "default answer" if you'd like.

Comment: It was important to know that the class of a mock object can be incomplete. Thank you!

Comment: @jeff so spy is more suitable to implementation or rather class than interface?

Comment: @Pramod A spy lets you override or record interaction with _a real instance_. You can't create a real instance of an interface class without some concrete class implementation, and even if you technically could, you're defeating the purpose: if there's no instance or behavior to pass through to, you might as well mock.